# Tags vs. categories for website content?

Tags: tags, seo, categories, user-experience, information-retrieval

I am creating a site for electronics and programming projects and articles, and I'm trying to figure out whether to use categories, tags or both. I've been leaning towards just using tags, as it's done here on StackOverflow.

Seen from the perspective of the user, what provides the best user experience and makes the information easy and intuitive to find. I realize that this is much a question of personal preference, but I am interested in hearing opinions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is what I ended up doing: I implemented both categories and tags; a post can only have one category but multiple tags.

The category is used as part of the URL, this puts a keyword in the URL which is good for SEO and it makes the URLs more structured. The categories are selected from a drop-down menu, and they are required. Categories are type specific, meaning articles will probably not have the same categories as projects or images.

```
articles/foobar                 // Show all articles with the category foobar
articles/1/foobar/article_slug  // View a specific article
```

Tags can be added and attached to a posts simply by typing them with comma separation, they are used in the meta keywords field. I don't think that matters much to SEO, but they are available so why not. Multiple tags can be attached to a post, but at least one is required. Tags are not type specific but universal, meaning that all resources may share the same tags. So a search for a tag may return articles, projects and images.

```
tags                    // Show all tags, and number of resources that use them
tags/foobar             // Show all resources with the tag foobar   
articles/tagged/foobar  // Show all articles with the tag foobar
```